# Pagination : get total number of page

Tags: php, web-services, pagination

I am making a web service for an application

I have a SQL Query which gets data in pagination manner.

I want the total number of pages for the data I get.

```html
  $limit = 10; // limit of 10 records
  $offset = ($page_number -1) * $limit; // calculate offset

 $userQuery="SELECT faq_question, faq_answer FROM `faq` WHERE faq_event_id = $event_id
                    LIMIT $limit 
                     OFFSET $offset";
```

Above is my Query.

**$page_number** would be a parameter to be passed.

How can I get total number of page used to display all data based on certain condition.

Thank You.

Comment: `$total_pages = $total_records / $limit` you just need to find total records using query without offset and limit.

Answer (score 3):

```
// I guess you use mysqli
// use another query without limitation
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT faq_question, faq_answer FROM `faq` WHERE faq_event_id = $event_id");

// total row count
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows; 

// total pages
$pages = ceil($row_cnt/$limit);
```

What I did here, first calculate total rows in database, then I divided total number of rows using limit. I used `ceil` for round value to up.( `echo ceil(6.3);`    // 7 pages)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to get count of all records and then apply calculation on that.

`count(total_records)/total_records_per_page`

it will give you the total pages which you want to get

Comment: let say I have 40 records which I get from   `$number=mysqli_num_rows($result)` and I have $limit of 10 so I get 4 pages using equation as `$total_page = $number / $limit;` am I doing right?